# does the isolate's port send message use the socket?

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

The different isolate communicate with each other by the port, does the port is the socket's port, use the socket send and receive message from each other?

Comment: This is a good question. I had not thought about this before. It seemed to me that messages were sent by email.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you try write it in another way and make it more clear?